# "Add Row" logic not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It has taken me days to come up with the following, and now I'm realizing that it still doesn't work. My "add row" button isn't working properly. What am I missing?

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>field</th>
        <th>comparison</th>
        <th>value</th>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select style="width:5em;" class="field">
                <option>name</option>
                <option>age</option>
                <option>sex</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select style="width:5em;" class = "comp">
                <option>equals</option>
                <option>starts with</option>
                <option>not equal to</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class = 'value'></td>
        <td><button id="add">Add row</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```javascript
$('#tableSearchMainAccount1 tr').each(function() {
    var td = '';
    // used to skip table header (if there is)
    if ($(this).find("td:first").length > 0) {
        $(this).find('option:selected').each(function() {
            td = td + $(this).text() + ',';
        });
        td = td + $(this).find('input').val();
        filt[ctr] = td;
        ctr += 1;
    }
});
//alert(filt); //alert output like  name,equals,ann,age,equals,11

$('#add').live('click', function() {
    var $lastTr = $('table tr:last');
    console.log($lastTr);
    $lastTr.clone().insertAfter($lastTr);
    // Remove the button from the previous tr, otherwise each row will have it.
    $('#add', $lastTr)
        .replaceWith('<button class="remove_row">Remove row</button>');
});

$('.remove_row').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: What is broken? What behavior are you expecting, and what instead are you seeing?

Comment: Well maybe because you don't have any id's or class names in your HTML? What is this? -> #tableSearchMainAccount1

Comment: nothing broken.. it just didnt work with me

Comment: @SyazriAris _"nothing broken.. it just didnt work with me"_ ... what?

Comment: @SyazriAris What do you mean it doesn't work? We can't help you if it's not broken or behaving incorrectly. What do you want it to do?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? You should think about not using the .live at it's deprecated.

Comment: @JonathanSampson the 'add row' button didnt work with me.. for your information, i took it from other post.. they show it here http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/w9fXJ/1/ but, when i try on my own, it didnt work..

Comment: @SyazriAris Did you place the JavaScript within `<script>` tags?

Comment: @JonathanSampson yes.. i placed it..

Comment: @SyazriAris Press F12, and look at your console. Does it have any errors when you run the page, and attempt to add rows?

Comment: @JonathanSampson ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @SyazriAris You're not referencing jQuery. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments, it appears you have not referenced jQuery.

[image]

Add the following to your `<head></head>` section:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

There are many other CDNs that host jQuery for you, or you can download it yourself. All of these details can be found on http://jquery.com/download/.

So that your markup looks something like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My jQuery Project</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>...</table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that I also referenced another external file called "scripts.js". This is where you could place all of your JavaScript and jQuery logic.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Wrapping your code with a document-ready
       block will ensure that the DOM will be
       ready before your code runs
    */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<table>
```

with

```
 <table id="tableSearchMainAccount1">
```

would be my starter for 10.